# How to fine-tune pre-trained model?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, classification, pytorch, transfer-learning

I'm trying to classify a data set of medical images with a pre-trained model EfficientNetB0. I've written a code in Python with Pytorch to train my model and fine-tune it but I would like to know if this is the correct approach.

First I replace the final layer of the model with a new untrained classifier:

```
batch_size = 10
learning_rate = 0.001

# Cross-validation
train_loader, validation_loader = split_dataset(balanced_dataset, batch_size)

# Define loss
criterion_class = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Load pre-trained model
model = timm.create_model('efficientnet_b0', pretrained=True, in_chans=1)

# Freeze parameters of feature extraction layers
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False

# Get the number of input features to the classifier
sample_input = torch.randn(1, 1, image_size, image_size)
features_output = model.forward_features(sample_input)
num_ftrs = features_output.shape[1]

# Define your custom classification head
class CustomClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features, num_classes):
        super(CustomClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(in_features, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc(x)
        return x

model.classifier = CustomClassifier(num_ftrs, num_classes)
model.to(device)

optimizer = optim.RMSprop(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
```

Next, I train the model and adjust the parameters of the last layer. Then I run the following code to unfreeze the whole model and change the learning rate:

```
# Unfreeze all parameters of the model
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = True

optimizer = optim.RMSprop(model.parameters(), lr=0.0002)
```

Then I train the model again and finish the tuning.

I would be glad to hear if this is the right way to it and any suggestions for improvement are much appresiated.

Comment: Did you obtain good results?